# What are the best practise to audit and display AR changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, audit

I need to monitor user changes on active record level with associations. This changes should be displayed on a stream like page. Since every user has different permission on different areas of my application also the audit stream has to be limited to their permissions.

I know about Paper trail (does not work on all type of relations:( ), Vestal versions, acts_as_audit and so on, but do not know what is the best practise to use this gems as described in my case.

What is the best practise to audit AR changes including associations and display in an activity stream with different user rights ?

Comment: Take a look at this presentation http://www.slideshare.net/danmckinley/etsy-activity-feeds-architecture. It describes activity streams architecture close to your needs. Hope you'll find it useful.

Comment: Thanks, was interesting to read. But this seems to be a bit over the top for my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to audit AR activities is provided by Rails with [Observer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html).

Observer allows to add callback function on Models. You can then update an *Acitivty* model allowing to see what has been changed. Take note that Observer are independent of Controller. What or Whoever change your model should pass through your observer. The drawback is that it can slow down your application.

A more efficient but also more complicated way would be to use [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/). See [this article](http://www.railsfire.com/article/ruby-eventmachine-short-introduction) for an introduction about it.

A way between EventMachine and Observer could be to use [delayed jobs](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) with Observers. If you have to compute something when auditing, it can allow you to do it without slowing down your application like a sleeping turtle. There's some good tips [here](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/5-tips-for-deploying-background-jobs/) about Delayed Jobs.